# ASP.NET Repeater Control Checkbox issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Overview: Clicking on *text* of first CheckBox in a repeater control clicks the *last one*. I know why this is happening; association of `label` tag with element id `chkMarkedForDeletion` and when that label is clicked it selects the last CheckBox, as all the CheckBoxes have same ID.. damn you repeater control!! I am wondering if there is any way to avoid this? Easy way would be to create individual labels and associate correctly to each CheckBox but that defeats the supposed default behaviour of a CheckBox.

Repeater code:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="childNodesDataRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table style="width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 200px;">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkMarkedForDeletion" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Text="Remove"
                        Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsMarkedForDeletion") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;
                </td>
                <td style="width: 200px;">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHighImpactCause" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Text="High Impact Cause"
                        Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IsHighPriority") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:Label ID="header002" runat="server" Text="What caused this problem?" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProblemCausedBy" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Width="100%"
                        Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %>' /><br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="height: 5px;">
                    <hr />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="nodeIdentifier" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" Value='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AnalysisID") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Generated HTML Code for CheckBox:

```
<INPUT id=chkMarkedForDeletion type=checkbox name=TabContainer$tabProblemResolution$frmProblemResolution1$childNodesDataRepeater$ctl00$chkMarkedForDeletion>
<LABEL for=chkMarkedForDeletion>Remove</LABEL>
...
...
<INPUT id=chkMarkedForDeletion type=checkbox name=TabContainer$tabProblemResolution$frmProblemResolution1$childNodesDataRepeater$ctl02$chkMarkedForDeletion>
<LABEL for=chkMarkedForDeletion>Remove</LABEL>
```

Issue:
[image: Repeater Issue ScreenShot]

Thanks,
Abhi

Comment: What ASP.NET version are you running, and what is your Client ID generation policy?

Comment: Asp.NET 4.0; Client ID generation policy is default, I haven't marked it as Static. I tried changing the Client ID gen. policy but did not make much difference. :(

Comment: Well it should generate different IDs automatically, unless you set the ClientIDMode=Static. Does this happen on other repeaters?

Comment: Did you copy that generated HTML verbatim?

Comment: @RomanRoyter I haven't tried other repeaters yet. @ Mike No, I copied this from IE Developer tools, not from source code, I couldn't find anything generated for repeater there.

Comment: @RomanRoyter I tried a simple project in Chrome and it worked fine!! Good point there...

Comment: And it is resolved by specifying `ClientIDMode="Predictable"`. @RomanRoyter Can you change your suggestion to an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode.aspx) on the repeater is not set to "Static".

This setting is inheritable from the parent, which goes all the way up to web.config. So if you have to set the ClientIDMode explicitly on the repeater, it means that some parent overrides the default (Predictable) to "Static".